# Reactjs Ref in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a button generator using react.
[image]
So, when user click get code, it'll get outerHTML of **Green Button(Whatsapp button)**. But in react, what i know to get element is using ref. the problem is the **Green button** different components with **Get The Code** button. 
Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

import ButtonCanvas from '../containers/buttonCanvas';
import ButtonGroup from './buttonGroup';

import SectionHeading from '../../commons/SectionHeading';
import TabComponent from '../../commons/tabs';

const ButtonBuilder = () => {
  const items = [
    {
      name: 'HTML Code',
      content: "Result 1",
    },
    {
      name: 'JS Code',
      content: 'Result 2',
    },
    {
      name: 'CSS Code',
      content: 'Result 3',
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <SectionHeading headingText="Button Setup" />
      <ButtonCanvas />
      <ButtonGroup />
      <TabComponent
        tabList={items}
        activeTab={items[0].name}
        tabStyle="is-medium"
        additionalClass="is-fullwidth"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ButtonBuilder;
```

`ButtonCanvas` is **Green Button** Component and`ButtonGroup` is component of **Get The Code** Button
So, when user click `ButtonGroup` it will get ref value from `ButtonCanvas` and place it to `const items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to pass a value of the ref from  the `<ButtonCanvas />` component is to save the value of the ref into a state in your parent component and then passing the state to the other child of your app like this `<ButtonCanvas {...this.state} />`
then you can access the state from your child element as a props
you can find in this link a basic example on how to pass data between element

https://gist.github.com/sebkouba/a5ac75153ef8d8827b98